# What are some standard methods for solving functional equations?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I have searched the internet for methods on solving functional equations, unfortunately, most of them consist mainly of substituting values for the variables or on guessing solutions. I think those methods sound like either an impossible task due to the infinite number of possible substitutions or a leap of faith due also to the infinite number of guesses there can be.

How could one for example solve:
$$f(1+x)=1+f(x)^2$$
I have tried many different ideas on this, from trying guesses to applying integrals, to eliminating the $1$ by calculating $f(2+x)$ and subtracting equations, then trying to simplify the answer through sums or products, but nothing seems to work.

I think this is a rather interesting subject because $f(x)=f(x-1)^2$ has a solution that is very easy to find but somehow adding a $1$ makes it a much harder problem. Are there ways to solve this equation or even a polynomial functional equation?

Comment: For this example you can take f to be anything on [0,1), then the rule determines what f is on [1,2), etc...

Comment: But can it be solved? Can $f$ be expressed explicitely?

Comment: There are so many solutions that you have to be more specific about what you're looking for.  For example, the equation has no polynomial solutions (Let $f(x)= a_nx^n+...+a_0$, you get a $2n$ degree polynomial equals an $n$ degree one, contradiction).  You could plug in f(x)= a power series, and derive some relationship between the coefficients.

Comment: Perhaps the difference between your easily-solvable and unsolvable examples can be traced back to the differences between a homogeneous (easy case) and inhomogeneous (hard case) difference equation? I think your two examples are not exactly difference equations, but maybe you can find some insight from that point of view? More generally, I recently stumbled onto [this website](http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=338).

Comment: With @mathematician comments, the problem as stated is solved. If you add some smoothness condition, such as ask the function to be continuos or differentiable, I guess maybe by trying to set the "initial condition" on [0,1) of the same smootheness, and some "boundary condition" on the 0 and the 1 to match continuity/differentiability in the integers, that should be steps toward solution of that problem ,but the stated one in question, pointed how to solve it.

Comment: @jjstankowicz The problem is a uncountable number of independent and identical difference equations, $a_{n+1} = 1+a_n^2$

Answer (score 4):

As for iterating polynomials, there are two general forms of polynomials that we currently know how to iterate. They are polynomials of the form
$$P(x)=a(x-b)^d+b$$
and
$$T(x)=\cos(k\arccos(x))$$
and yes, I know the second one doesn't look like a polynomial, but for integer values of $k$, it is a polynomial where the inverse cosine is defined, and can be extended to other values (accurately, for our purposes) using the hyperbolic cosine function. For more info, see [Chebyshev Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

The iteration formulas for each of these is given by
$$P^n(x)=a^{\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}}(x-b)^{d^n}+b$$
and
$$T^n(x)=\cos(k^n\arccos(x))$$

In case you were wondering how this applies to your problem of finding $f$ given that
$$f(1+n)=(Q\circ f)(n)$$
where $Q$ is a polynomial, here's how: if you assign a value for $f(0)$, say $y_0$, then you can say that
$$f(n)=(Q^n\circ f)(0)=Q^n(y_0)$$
which allows you to find $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$.